# Transform flat into nested object

Tags: javascript, nested

I cannot figure out how to transform flat objects with arrays of parents into actual nested (tree) hierarchy objects. It basically all boils down to following question:

How can I turn a sample object such as

```
var sample = {
    name: '1.1.1.1',
    parents: [{
        name: '1.1.1'
    }, {
        name: '1.1'
    }, {
        name: '1'
    }]
};
```

... efficiently into following result:

```
var result = [{
    name: '1',
    children: [{
        name: '1.1',
        children: [{
            name: '1.1.1',
            children: [{
                name: '1.1.1.1'
            }]
        }] 
    }]
}];
```

The names are arbitrarily chosen and `sample` could theoretically be of unlimited depth.

Unfortunately, `result` and `children` need to be an array of objects, because my actual use case is a little more complex and consists of multiple `sample` objects. It models a best practice to [manage hierarchical data in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org):

```
var result = _.reduce(sample.parents, function(memo, node) {
    node.children = [memo];
    return node;
}, {name: sample.name});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I could even remove the dependency on Underscore with the native [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) implementation, since I only need to support IE9+ :)